# Silverlight never executing code on UI Thread throught dispatcher on WP 8.1

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-8

my goal here is to play some animation and make the UI wait until it is finished to execute some other code. I have a class like this:

```
 class Game
    {
       private string currentClickedCommand;
       private string currentClickedSlot;
       private GamePage gamePage;// gamePage na kojem se vrsi radnja
       private string[] chosenCommands;// ovo je string array u kojem su sadrzana imena odabranih komandi
       private int chapterNumber;
       // Kontekst stranice koristen za update objekata UI

       // Za kontrolu animacija
       public static bool isAnimationComplete;
       private BitmapImage currentImage;

       public Game(GamePage gp, int chapterNum)
       {
           currentClickedCommand = null;
           currentClickedSlot = null;
           gamePage = gp;
           chapterNumber = chapterNum;
           isAnimationComplete = false;
           chosenCommands = new string[5];
           gamePage.characterRectangle.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
           Thread AnimationThread = new Thread(playIntroAnimation);
           AnimationThread.Start();
           while (!isAnimationComplete) { }
           loadCommands();
           loadSlots();
       }

       public void playIntroAnimation() {
               // Pretpostavljam da na osnovu baze znam koja je animacija za ovaj chapter navedena kao uvodna
           Debug.WriteLine("on other thread playing animation");
               // Sakrivam gridove komandi i ostalog

               Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
               {
                   gamePage.CommandGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                   gamePage.SlotGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                   MessageBox.Show("Prvi dispatch");
                   Debug.WriteLine("prvi dispatch");
               }));
               // Ucitavam pozadinsku sliku preko canvasa cijelog
               Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
               {
                   ImageBrush bgImage = new ImageBrush();
                   Uri imgSource = new Uri(@"Assets/Chapter backgrounds/chapter_1_introduction.png", UriKind.Relative);
                   BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(imgSource);
                   bgImage.ImageSource = img;
                   gamePage.mainCanvas.Background = bgImage;
                   MessageBox.Show("Drugi dispatch");
               }));
               // Kreiram parametre animacije
               Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
               {
                   Uri sheetSource = new Uri(@"Assets/Sheets/test_wave_sheet.png", UriKind.Relative);
                   currentImage = new BitmapImage(sheetSource);
                   currentImage.ImageOpened += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(setAnimationParams);
                   Image i = new Image();
                   i.Source = currentImage;
                   MessageBox.Show("Treci dispatch");
               }));
               // Odredjujem lika i animiram ga -- visinu i sirinu znam iz baze(kad dobavim sheet i ostalo imam gotove parametere
               // sada moram hardkodirat radi testa
               Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
               {
                   gamePage.characterRectangle.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                   Canvas.SetLeft(gamePage.characterRectangle, gamePage.mainCanvas.ActualWidth / 4.0);
                   Canvas.SetTop(gamePage.characterRectangle, gamePage.mainCanvas.ActualHeight / 5.0);
                   MessageBox.Show("Cetvrti dispatch");
               }));

       }

       private void setAnimationParams(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
               AnimationClasses.AnimationParams parameters = new AnimationClasses.AnimationParams(currentImage, 462, 438, 7, true, currentImage.PixelWidth, false, 2);
               new AnimationClasses.Animation().Animate(gamePage.characterRectangle, parameters);
           }); 
       }
```

As you can see, I've been trying to do this using Deployment.Current... etc. but no luck. I have been debugging but it simply never gets into executing this code and nothing is happening.

I create an instance of Game on Page like this:

```
public GamePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            game = new Game(this,    Convert.ToInt32(PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["chapter"]));

        }
```

I have a static attribute(isAnimationComplete) which is set elsewhere to true, when the animation is complete. The 2 commands after(loadCommands, loadSlots) need to wait for this to finish and then execute.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have a deadlock.

The UI thread is calling the constructor of the `Game` class. Inside, you're starting a background thread, then waiting in a loop:

```
while (!isAnimationComplete) { }
```

Which means that the UI thread won't be available for other operations until you set the `isAnimationComplete` flag to true. Which will never happen since you're doing that when the animations are done executing... Animations that are waiting for the UI thread to be free.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what happened, I have since solved it.